# 64 bit version of boinc client requires X while 32 bit version does not?

Tags: 11.10, server

I am attempting to install `boinc-client` on a few Ubuntu Server machines. However there's one problem: With both depending on the same libraries (just different architectures), one requires X while the other one doesn't?

Both servers a fairly vanilla with not much installed besides the base image. Both are running Ubuntu Server 11.10. Command run was `sudo apt-get install boinc-client`

32 bit machine

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  boinc-client libcurl3
```

64 bit machine

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  boinc-client fontconfig:i386 ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32ffi6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
  lib32ncursesw5 lib32stdc++6 lib32tinfo5 libacl1:i386 libasound2 libattr1:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libcups2:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libcurl3 libcurl3:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386
  libgdbm3:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libice6:i386 libidn11:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms1:i386
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm2.9:i386 libmng1:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
  libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-designer:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386 libqt4-script:i386
  libqt4-scripttools:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386
  libqtgui4:i386 librtmp0:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsm6:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-3:i386
  libtiff4:i386 libuuid1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxi6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 qdbus:i386 x11-common
```

Why is there such a difference between the 64 bit and 32 bit versions? Both use the same libraries, so adding other nonsense doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the bionic-client is a 32 bit application, and the 64 bit install is pulling in all the 32 bit libs to go with it.

`i386` are 32 bit libs  ( fontconfig:**i386** )

Comment: the 32-bit machine doesn't have X. Even if its pulling in 32-bit versions of its dependencies, none of them depend on X

Comment: I am not familiar enough with bionic-client to know if it need all those libs or not. If not, consider filing a bug report so the dependencies can be reviewed in the package. I have noticed Ubuntu sometimes lists more then the bare bones dependencies, I suppose that is part of what makes it easy to use.

Comment: I went ahead an reported it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/boinc/+bug/905059

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question is quite old, but I was able to avoid installing all of those libs and get a working boinc-client/manager installed on 12.04 64-bit:

```
$ sudo aptitude install --without-recommends boinc-client boinc-manager
```

Or you can use the `apt-get` option `--no-install-recommends`.

I have yet to run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks! it avoided me to install a bunch of useless 32 bits libraries.